# ¿como editar y eliminar en laravel?

Tags: laravel, crud

hola amigos soy principiante en laravel y me gustaría que ayudara con este código para poder editar y eliminar, ya que el crear y el lista lo tengo.

**controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\ProductRepository;
use Illuminate\Http\Request,
    App\Repositories\ClientRepository,
    App\Repositories\InvoiceRepository,
    App\Http\Requests,
    PDF;

class InvoiceController extends Controller
{
    private $_clientRepo;
    private $_productRepo;
    private $_invoiceRepo;

    public function __CONSTRUCT(
        ClientRepository $clientRepo,
        ProductRepository $productRepo,
        InvoiceRepository $invoiceRepo
    )
    {
        $this->_clientRepo = $clientRepo;
        $this->_productRepo = $productRepo;
        $this->_invoiceRepo = $invoiceRepo;
    }

    public function index()
    {

        return view('invoice.index', ['model' => $this->_invoiceRepo->getAll()
            ]
        );
    }

    public function detail($id)
    {
        return view('invoice.detail', ['model' => $this->_invoiceRepo->get($id)
        ]);
    }


    public function pdf($id)
    {
        $model = $this->_invoiceRepo->get($id);

        $invoice_name = sprintf('comprobante-%s.pdf', str_pad ($model->id, 7, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice.pdf', ['model' => $model
        ]);

        return $pdf->download($invoice_name);
    }

    public function add()
    {
        return view('invoice.add');
    }

    public function save(Request $req)
    {
        $data = (object)[
            'iva' => $req->input('iva'),
            'subTotal' => $req->input('subTotal'),
            'total' => $req->input('total'),
            'client_id' => $req->input('client_id'),
            'detail' => []
        ];

        foreach($req->input('detail') as $d){
            $data->detail[] = (object)[
                'product_id' => $d['id'],
                'quantity'   => $d['quantity'],
                'unitPrice'  => $d['price'],
                'total'      => $d['total']
            ];
        }

        return $this->_invoiceRepo->save($data);
    }



    public function findClient(Request $req)
    {
        return $this->_clientRepo
                    ->findByName($req->input('q'));
    }

    public function findProduct(Request $req)
    {
        return $this->_productRepo
                    ->findByName($req->input('q'));
    }
}
```

**modelo**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model {

    public function detail(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\InvoiceItem');
    }


    public function client(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }
}
```

**repositorio**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Invoice;
use App\InvoiceItem;
use DB;

class InvoiceRepository {
    private $model;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->model = new Invoice();
    }

    public function get($id) {
        return $this->model->find($id);
    }

    public function getAll() {
        return $this->model->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    }

    public function save($data) {
        $return = (object)['response' => false];

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $this->model->iva = $data->iva;
            $this->model->subTotal = $data->subTotal;
            $this->model->total = $data->total;
            $this->model->client_id = $data->client_id;


            $this->model->save();

            $detail = [];
            foreach($data->detail as $d) {
                $obj = new InvoiceItem;

                $obj->product_id = $d->product_id;
                $obj->quantity = $d->quantity;
                $obj->unitPrice = $d->unitPrice;
                $obj->total = $d->total;

                $detail[] = $obj;
            }

            $this->model->detail()->saveMany($detail);
            $return->response = true;

            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e){
            DB::rollBack();
        }

        return json_encode($return);
    }


}
```

**vista listar**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" ><h2 class="page-header" align="center">FACTURAS</h2></div>

            <div class="panel-body">


<!--           <form class="navbar-form navbar-left pull-right" action="{{ route('Client.index') }}" method="get">

                </form>-->
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-block" href="{{url('invoice/add')}}">Nueva Factura</a>
            </div>


        <div class="table-container">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Clientes</th>
                        <th style="width:100px;" class="text-right">IVA</th>
                        <th style="width:160px;" class="text-right">Sub Total</th>
                        <th style="width:160px;" class="text-right">Total</th>
                        <th style="width:180px;" class="text-center">Creado</th>
                        <th style="width:180px;" class="text-center">Imprimir</th>
                        <th style="width:30px;"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($model as $m)
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">
                            <a href="{{url('invoice/detail/' . $m->id )}}">
                                {{ $m->client->name }}
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">$ {{number_format($m->iva, 2)}}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">$ {{number_format($m->subTotal, 2)}}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">$ {{number_format($m->total, 2)}}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">{{ $m->created_at  }}</td>


                        <td class="text-right">
                            <a class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-xs" href="{{ url('invoice/pdf/' . $m->id) }}">
                                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Descargar
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>

            </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach


                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**vista add**

```
    <invoice>
    <div class="well well-sm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input id="client" class="form-control typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Cliente" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Ruc" readonly value="{ruc}" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="DirecciÃ³n" readonly value="{address}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <input id="product" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre del producto" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input id="quantity" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Cantidad" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">S/.</span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Precio" value="{price}" readonly />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <button onclick={__addProductToDetail} class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="btn-agregar">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:40px;"></th>
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th style="width:100px;">Cantidad</th>
            <th style="width:100px;">P.U</th>
            <th style="width:100px;">Total</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr each={detail}>
            <td>
                <button onclick={__removeProductFromDetail} class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-block">X</button>
            </td>
            <td>{name}</td>
            <td class="text-right">{quantity}</td>
            <td class="text-right">$ {price}</td>
            <td class="text-right">$ {total}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><b>IVA</b></td>
            <td class="text-right">$ {iva.toFixed(2)}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><b>Sub Total</b></td>
            <td class="text-right">$ {subTotal.toFixed(2)}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><b>Total</b></td>
            <td class="text-right">$ {total.toFixed(2)}</td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <button if={detail.length > 0 && client_id > 0} onclick={__save} class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">
        Guardar
    </button>

    <script>
        var self = this;

        // Detalle del comprobante
        self.client_id = 0;
        self.detail = [];
        self.iva = 0;
        self.subTotal = 0;
        self.total = 0;

        self.on('mount', function(){
            __clientAutocomplete();
            __productAutocomplete();
        })

        __removeProductFromDetail(e) {
            var item = e.item,
                index = this.detail.indexOf(item);

            this.detail.splice(index, 1);
            __calculate();
        }

        __addProductToDetail() {
            self.detail.push({
                id: self.product_id,
                name: self.product.value,
                quantity: parseFloat(self.quantity.value),
                price: parseFloat(self.price),
                total: parseFloat(self.price * self.quantity.value)
            });

            self.product_id = 0;
            self.product.value = '';
            self.quantity.value = '';
            self.price = '';

            __calculate();
        }

        __save() {
            $.post(baseUrl('invoice/save'), {
                client_id: self.client_id,
                iva: self.iva,
                subTotal: self.subTotal,
                total: self.total,
                detail: self.detail
            }, function(r){
                if(r.response) {
                    window.location.href = baseUrl('invoice');
                } else {
                    alert('Ocurrio un error');
                }
            }, 'json')
        }

        function __calculate() {
            var total = 0;

            self.detail.forEach(function(e){
                total += e.total;
            });

            self.total = total;
            self.subTotal = parseFloat(total / 1.19);
            self.iva = parseFloat(total - self.subTotal);
        }

        function __clientAutocomplete(){
            var client = $("#client"),
                options = {
                url: function(q) {
                    return baseUrl('invoice/findClient?q=' + q);
                },
                getValue: 'name',
                list: {
                    onClickEvent: function() {
                        var e = client.getSelectedItemData();
                        self.client_id = e.id;
                        self.ruc = e.ruc;
                        self.address = e.address;

                        self.update();
                    }
                }
            };

            client.easyAutocomplete(options);
        }

        function __productAutocomplete(){
            var product = $("#product"),
                options = {
                url: function(q) {
                    return baseUrl('invoice/findProduct?q=' + q);
                },
                getValue: 'name',
                list: {
                    onClickEvent: function() {
                        var e = product.getSelectedItemData();
                        self.product_id = e.id;
                        self.price = e.price;

                        self.update();
                    }
                }
            };

            product.easyAutocomplete(options);
        }
    </script>
</invoice>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola te propongo que revises este sitio [InfyOm Laravel Geneator](http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/docs/5.6/introduction), `InfyOm` es un paquete laravel-api-generator package permite la creación de API y andamios de tipo CRUD para simplificarnos la vida. En unos pocos días obtuvo una gran atracción y la comunidad laravel comenzó a usarlo con varios problemas, solicitudes de extracción y solicitudes de funciones. Soportado para Laravel en sus versiones 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5 & 5.6

Espero te sirva